# Limiting access with Custom Metadata types

Tags: custom-metadata

We are implementing a high-security project which will be manage packaged.We are planning to use custom metadata types to store master data in 2 tables. These 2 tables are like a master->detail.I had a plan to make them Protected so that the subscriber org is not allowed to edit/delete.
If the records are Protected, then can the subscriber org edit the existing records using Metadata API?

Please share your knowledge/opinion on this question.

Comment: No. Subscriber org can't do anything with protected records by any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge and understanding, once you create your manage package which will include custom metadata records as well are not editable/deletable, but then the end environment can add the records on top of it. In custom metadata the records are similar to metadata in `Custom Metadata Types`, So after building manage package the user will not be able to delete like any other manage package components.

Refer below link for more details:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/custom_metadata_types/units/custom_metadata_types_manageability